# Android: Is it possible to get other apps notification info?

Tags: android, android-notifications, accessibilityservice

I have question about Accessibility Service in Android.
Can I catch a notification in status bar and get info from  notification?

My purpose is to catch notification of apps like Viber, Skype.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can check out NotificationListenerService. Not sure if it answers what you need but according to the docs:

> A service that receives calls from the system when new notifications are posted or removed, or their ranking changed.

You can get the active notifications with **getActiveNotifications()**.
Though I have never tested this and do not know if it gets other apps notifications in the  status bar or only yours.

This is the current description of that method:

> Request the list of outstanding notifications (that is, those that are visible to the current user). Useful when you don't know what's already been posted.

You can get more info @ [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html)

Note: This method is only available on API 18.

Further investigation I've found an example made by another user on how to use NotificationListenerService:

https://github.com/kpbird/NotificationListenerService-Example

AccessibilityService is to handle accessibility touches:

> An accessibility service runs in the background and receives callbacks
> by the system when AccessibilityEvents are fired. Such events denote
> some state transition in the user interface, for example, the focus
> has changed, a button has been clicked, etc. Such a service can
> optionally request the capability for querying the content of the
> active window. Development of an accessibility service requires
> extending this class and implementing its abstract methods.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [NotificationListenerService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html), it's easy to use, look at [this blog post](http://gmariotti.blogspot.it/2013/11/notificationlistenerservice-and-kitkat.html).